# Why is UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() available globally?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, uikit, uigraphicscontext

From [Apple iOS Documentation #UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html): "In iOS 4 and later, you may call this function from any thread of your app."

Also, why is the method call in C function format 
`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` and not Objective-C message format `[UIView UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some APIs on iOS that are accessed via C and not ObjC objects. CoreGraphics for drawing (all of the `CG*` functions) is one of the most important ones.

Direct drawing is typically done into a `CGContextRef`, which represents a graphics context. UIKit keeps a stack of contexts for drawing (typically you won't interact much beyond the current context). This stack is accessed by global C functions because you can use them from anywhere. Typically, they are accessed from inside of `drawRect:`, but you can use this stack elsewhere. [Per the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html):

> If you are not using a UIView object to do your drawing, however, you
>   must push a valid context onto the stack manually using the
>   UIGraphicsPushContext function.

Comment: Can you complete the following sentence: "You need a graphic context when..." Is it when I need to draw a line, move from point to point? stroke and fill it? What else?